# Assembly 8088: 32-bit signed Multiplication with addition and bit manipulation using 16-bit registers

Tags: assembly, 32-bit, cpu-architecture, x86-16

I am trying to write assembly program to multiply two 32-bit signed numbers and store the answer in 64-bit number but my code only gives me the correct answer up to 32-bits. I have goggled it and searched many sites but can't satisfy myself. I can't get the problem although i debugged it many times.This is my first question as a student so I am really sorry if I am unclear.Thanks :)

```
; 32bit multiplication 
[org 0x0100]
multiplicand dd 0,9000008             ; 32bit multiplicand 64bit space 
multiplier: dd 45009                  ; 32bit multiplier 
result: dd 0,0                        ; 64bit result 
start:
    mov cx,32                         ; initialize bit count to 32
    mov bx, [multiplier]              ; load multiplier in dx and bx
    mov dx, [multiplier+2]            

checkbit:
    sar dx,1                          ; move right most bit in carry 
    rcr bx,1
    jnc skip                          ; skip addition if bit is zero
    mov ax,[multiplicand]
    add word[result],ax
    mov ax,[multiplicand+2]
    adc word[result+2],ax
    mov ax,[multiplicand+4]
    adc word[result+4],ax
    mov ax,[multiplicand+6]
    adc word[result+6],ax
    mov ax,[multiplicand+8]
    adc word[result+8],ax
    mov ax,[multiplicand+10]
    adc word[result+10],ax
    mov ax,[multiplicand+12]
    adc word[result+12],ax
    mov ax,[multiplicand+14]
    adc word[result+14],ax

skip:
    shl word [multiplicand],1
    rcl word [multiplicand+2],1
    rcl word [multiplicand+4],1
    rcl word [multiplicand+6],1
    rcl word [multiplicand+8],1
    rcl word [multiplicand+10],1
    rcl word [multiplicand+12],1
    rcl word [multiplicand+14],1
    dec cx
    jnz checkbit

mov ax,0x4c00                         ; terminate program
int 0x21
```

I think my logic is right but then i can't get what the error is. Any help is appreciated.    :)

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged the program?

Comment: I get your point. I pressed F1 key on AFD debugger until cx became zero and then matched the answer with calculator. i got that it becomes wrong after 32-bits. I should have thoroughly done that :P..... well thank you @RaymondChen ..:)

Comment: That's not really debugging if you check the value only at the end. Try checking the value more frequently, like, say, each time execution reaches `checkbit`, or even after every instruction, seeing as the program is so brief. (It executes only a few hundred instructions, You should be able to step through every single one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
multiplicand dd 0,9000008             ; 32bit multiplicand 64bit space
```

You setup 64 bit space but your code modifies 128 bit space!!

Also because of little endeanness you should swap the dwords of the multiplicand.

Comment: Thanks..i checked it...it's done.. actually i thought for every four bit in binary, there is addition of one bit in hexadecimal but logically i made a mistake and added two bits per four bit and now thanks to you. i get it..Also Little Endian thingy..